# Are class attributes and method local variables thread safe in singleton class in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, singleton

I found few answers for this question but all answers were java based. And they were quite java specific. It might look like a repeat but I couldn't find any answer for python.

I have a singleton class:

```py
class A():
    _lock = threading.Lock()

    def __new__(cls):
        obj = cls.__dict__.get("__it__")
        if obj is not None:
            return obj
        with cls._lock:
            if obj is None:
                cls.__it__ = obj = object.__new__(cls)
                obj.init()
        return obj
    
    def init(self):
        self.value = 2
        
    def call_me(self, input):
        self.value = input
        temp = self.value
        print(temp)

# two threads call the function at exactly same time.

# thread 1 calls
A().call_me(5)

# thread 2 calls
A().call_me(7)
```

Now if two threads make the objects of A, then I am assured its thread safe as its a double locked checking pattern. But is the class attribute `self.value` and method variable `temp` thread safe?

Because if it's the same instance of A for both the threads, then both threads will be able to change the value and then it's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, the call_me method is not thread-safe. The lock is used to make sure only one instance of this class is created, that is, it's the singleton pattern.